# How to echo mysql CURRENT_DATE() in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to compare PHP:

```
$now = date('Y-d-m H:i:s');
```

with mysql `CURRENT_DATE()` and `die();`

I need to check if the mysql `current_date` is the same as `$now`.

However, I don't know how to do that. I would probably need some format change to `CURRENT_DATE()` too so I can compare it with `$now = date('Y-d-m H:i:s');`

Is this possible?

If yes, what would php code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL the `CURDATE()` returns the current date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format or 'YYYYMMDD' format depending on whether numeric or string is used in the function.

`CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_DATE()` are the synonym of `CURDATE()`.

```
SELECT CURDATE();
```

[image]

**Example of MySql - curdate() function**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT CURDATE()");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
echo $row['CURDATE()'] ;
}
```

**Example of MySql - curdate() function in numeric format**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT CURDATE()+1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo $row['CURDATE()+1'];

}
```

i have used the mysql_* function only for i understand i don't recommended to use mysql_* function

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use strtotime to convert date returned by MYSQL into Unix timestamp and then compare it with time:

```
$q = "SELECT CURRENT_DATE() date";
$res = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
if(time() == strtotime($res['date'])) // dates are equal, proceded with your logic
```

or you could also do it a bit wierd like that if you please:

```
if (strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) == strtotime($row['date']))
```

but the first version would be cleaner